# Cannot see "Store Apps" project templates in Visual Studio 2013 ultimate update 4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

I want to develop Window Phone 8.1 application, but I cannot find project template for it in Visual Studio.

I think this panel should contain "Store Apps" template (Universal Apps, Windows Apps and Windows Phone apps)

I already re-installed VS, but still error. Please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS are you on? These won't show up on OSes earlier than Windows 8.1.

Comment: You're right. I used windows 7. I have to install Windows 8.1 instead. Thanks for your response